# Spring boot auth server client/ resource server: OAuth 2.1 Authorization Code Grant programatic simulation? Password grant no longer exists

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Spring Authorization Server OAuth 2.1.

How can i programatically simulate the authorization_code grant?

Since all grants except for  authorization_code and client_credentials have been dropped this has become quite a headache.

The scenario calls for a @Scheduled job to login as a specific user where the client credentials are encoded properties within the server performing the login.
The user roles are important when executing downstream resources and is considered a regular user of the registered Client.

Using the Password grant was perfect for this scenario in OAuth 2.0.

Before i start hacking our Spring Auth server and implement a Password grant for registered resources or maybe overloading the client_credentials for user_credentialed payloads.

Quite a pain if you ask me, so please enlighten me? Are there any patterns for implementing this that i have not yet discovered?

Comment: If I'm understanding your scenario correctly, you're trying to build an authorization server that authenticates regular users and a scheduled task that uses their roles (via a token returned by the server) to perform the job, is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly that, but incorporating spring-boot-starter-client to handle the ClientRegistrations/Repository etc for the automated user login from the @Scheduled tasks. So nothing strange for the regular Resource Server at all.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm curious what specific use case you have that needs to perform tasks as a particular user (as opposed to a single confidential client), it should still be possible with customization.

> maybe overloading the client_credentials for user_credentialed payloads

This approach makes the most sense to me as a way to adapt supported flows in OAuth 2.1 to emulate a deprecated flow like the resource owner `password` grant. You can use a variation of [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/sjohnr/59eafc8e7f0b0c3ee96f3becd248676f), extending it with your user's authorities if needed. One possible solution might look like the following:

```java
@Component
public final class DaoRegisteredClientRepository implements RegisteredClientRepository {
    private final RegisteredClient registeredClient;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public DaoRegisteredClientRepository(RegisteredClient registeredClient, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.registeredClient = registeredClient;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(RegisteredClient registeredClient) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public RegisteredClient findById(String id) {
        return this.registeredClient.getId().equals(id) ? this.registeredClient : null;
    }

    @Override
    public RegisteredClient findByClientId(String clientId) {
        UserDetails userDetails;
        try {
            userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(clientId);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ignored) {
            return null;
        }

        return RegisteredClient.from(this.registeredClient)
                .clientId(userDetails.getUsername())
                .clientSecret(userDetails.getPassword())
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().setting("user.authorities", userDetails.getAuthorities()).build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This uses a single client registration, but makes use of a `UserDetailsService` to resolve a `subject` representing your user's username and a `secret` which is actually the user's password. You would then need to provide an `@Bean` of type `OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext>` to access the `user.authorities` setting and add those authorities to the resulting access token (JWT) using whatever claim your resource server expects them in.

Alternatively, you could just override the `scopes` parameter of the returned `RegisteredClient` if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and ended up creating a password grant emulation servlet filter. Please refer to my example:
https://github.com/andreygrigoriev/spring_authorization_server_password_grant